# Laravel persistent $errors and old() input data for next requests and clearing them

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have been working on a controller that makes modifications on existing data. The initially received response gives the client a view where client can fill a form and submit it as POST request. After the POST request is handled, client gets redirected to the same page where he/she filled the form.

The problem here is, form is not actually part of that view that is acquired with GET request. The form is being loaded with the help of a button and AJAX request to another route. **This part is important: form is not part of the view, it is loaded with an AJAX request on that view.**

So, what is the problem? The problem is, I'm currently providing invalid data to the form so I can check out the validation system is working correctly. I should to feed client back with proper error messages and load the form with old inputs that the client has provided. But when I try that, I get the old input and errors on the view, after submitting the form. That's great, but once I click that button to load the form into the page and open it, there's no old input or error data. That is probably because Laravel's old input data and errors bag is only available for the next request. When the controller redirects the client to the route that responses with the view, it receives the error and old input data but when it loads the form by making an AJAX request, they are already cleaned.

To overcome this problem, I have been resetting the old input and errors with the same values for the next request, like below:

```php
@php
    session()->flash('errors', $errors);
    session()->flash('_old_input', request()->old());
@endphp
```

This solution was working good on the page that loads the creation but I also have the same mechanism for editing the added resource. Refreshing the old input and error data works for creating phase but doesn't work as well for editing. I have made sure I'm doing everything same for both actions, I checked it out but I couldn't find why there's such inconsistent behaviour. So I dediced to look up for another solution.

How do I make error data and old input data persistent? I will probably need to remove these session datas after the controller done its job or after showing the data to the user with the form view. How do I do that?